# I have a problem with my react native application. When I try to run my application, this message pops up:

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, debugging, stack-trace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkULZ.png)

I tried add into android studio setings>build, execution, deployment>compiler few opction into gradle, like "--stacktrace or --debug" but that dont work. Give me a few solutions what i can do with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Could not install the app on the device." It's clear that the Android environment hasn't been set up correctly. Refer to this [guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native)